# How to add spinner while async routes are loading?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

React Router can load routes asynchronously via `getComponent` or `getComponents` and it is ok. But if user has slow internet connection i should show some page with loader and some text message like 'Please wait component is loading' and so on. How to configure that using `getComponent`?

Comment: are you using Redux? then I have better solution for you ;)

Comment: @free-soul no, i don't, but anyway could you share solution using Redux

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `getComponent`, you should use `component` and provide it a component that shows a loading message by default, but once it has loaded a component it shows that component instead.

You can reference [this github gist](https://gist.github.com/acdlite/a68433004f9d6b4cbc83b5cc3990c194) for an example. It was written for React Router v4, but the idea is the same. Instead of rendering `null` you would reference the spinner, loader message, etc.

Comment: thanks for the answer, nevertheless it is strange that there is no inbuilt solution even in v4